# Enforcing lowest transaction isolation level across concurrent sessions?

Tags: postgresql, locking, distributed-transactions, postgresql-12, ctas

I am trying to learn transactions better in PostgreSQL and came across this observation.

I have a situation where I am creating multiple tables using an SQL statement across multiple sessions. I am using `CREATE TABLE *table_name* AS *sql_stmt*`  (CTAS) syntax. I would consider this a safe operation to execute concurrently (across my multiple sessions) because it is not updating any data, thus I would want to ensure that I have the least restrictive lock possible at all times.

That being said, multiple sessions are still creating data (the table) so I am quite worried that if the SQL statements contain references to the same table, I might be invoking a lock, even if I know that it is safe for the operations I have in mind. In other words, I know that all my operations are read-only (so can use a lock that is not restrictive) and that no table will have data which is updated, with the simple caveat that I am also saving the result as a table (so this is no longer 100% read-only; might invoke some restrictive lock at some point?). Thus, my question is as follows: how can I ensure the lowest lock restriction across all concurrent sessions while I do my CTAS workload?

For an example, let us say I have two sessions. One is issuing the following command:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 AS SELECT * FROM facttable;
```

The other, concurrently issues:

```
CREATE TABLE t2 AS SELECT * FROM facttable;
```

How can I ensure that such operations do not invoke a lock since they are referring to the same table?

Comment: I don't understand. Are these multiple sessions creating different tables? In different databases? Can you add some code and a more technical description?

Comment: Yes, multiple sessions creating different tables. Not sure what you mean with different databases, this is all being done on the same database cluster. I shall supply a small example soon.

Comment: Are you having performance problems? Locking problems? Or is this just theoretical? When you copy the data like you are doing, you don't prevent new data from being inserted -- you just won't see it or get it in the new table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no danger of locking with your scenario.

The only lock that is taken on `facttable` is the `ACCESS SHARE` lock that prevents others from dropping or altering the table while it is being read. Since `ACCESS SHARE` [doesn't conflict with itself](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#TABLE-LOCK-COMPATIBILITY), that is no problem (two people can read the same poster).

The only consideration is the I/O load: if many processes perform a sequential scan on the table, that could be substantial. You should try to benefit from PostgreSQL's [synchronized sequential scans](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-SYNCHRONIZE-SEQSCANS) by starting all processes at the same time, so that they have a chance to synchronize their sequential scans.

Comment: Just for clarification, with regards to the IO load consideration, this is something that should only happen when available memory is not sufficient, correct?

Comment: Well, if all is cached, you won't have I/O.